# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' when doing Seaborn Histplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I get the above mentioned Type Error when creating subplots of different histograms.

To give some context, I have a large dataset that I had to clean in several separate chunks to avoid memory issues. I saved each chunks individually and then proceeded to concatenate them together on another notebook.

When I ran my code to create the subplots with the chunked dataframes it was working fine, but when I ran the subplot code again with the concatenate data I get a Type Error. I don't understand why since I'm not changing anything really.

The error occurs here:

[image]

**My full code**

```
#Overall
CRev_All_age1 = df_optimized.groupby(['YearOnboarded', 'age_buckets']).sum().reset_index()
#Europe
CRev_EU = df_optimized.loc[df_optimized['Continents'] == 'Europe']
Plot_CRev_EU_age1 = CRev_EU.groupby(['YearOnboarded', 'age_buckets']).sum().reset_index()
#Asia
CRev_Asia = df_optimized.loc[df_optimized['Continents'] == 'Asia']
Plot_CRev_Asia_age1 = CRev_Asia.groupby(['YearOnboarded', 'age_buckets']).sum().reset_index()
#Other
CRev_Other = df_optimized.loc[(df_optimized['Continents'] != 'Europe') & (df_optimized['Continents'] != 'Asia')]
Plot_CRev_Other_age1 = CRev_Other.groupby(['YearOnboarded', 'age_buckets']).sum().reset_index()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, constrained_layout=True, figsize=(14,12))
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4 =axes.flatten()

#plot1
ax1 = sns.histplot( data=CRev_All_age1, x="YearOnboarded", hue="age_buckets",weights="Revenue2", multiple="stack", discrete=True, shrink=.9, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Overall - Client Revenue (Million)', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
ax1.tick_params('x', labelrotation=15)
ax1.set_ylabel('Revenue', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xlabel('Year Onboarded', fontsize=12)
#plot2
ax2 = sns.histplot( data=Plot_CRev_EU_age1, x="YearOnboarded", hue="age_buckets",weights="Revenue2", multiple="stack", discrete=True, shrink=.9, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Europe - Client Revenue (Million)', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.setp(ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=15)
ax2.set_ylabel('Revenue', fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xlabel('Year Onboarded', fontsize=12)
#plot3
ax3 = sns.histplot( data=Plot_CRev_Asia_age1, x="YearOnboarded", hue="age_buckets",weights="Revenue2", multiple="stack", discrete=True, shrink=.9, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('Asia - Client Revenue (Million)', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
for tick in ax3.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(15)
ax3.set_ylabel('Revenue', fontsize=12)
ax3.set_xlabel('Year Onboarded', fontsize=12)
#plot4
ax4 = sns.histplot( data=Plot_CRev_Other_age1, x="YearOnboarded", hue="age_buckets",weights="Revenue2", multiple="stack", discrete=True, shrink=.9, ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title('Other Continents - Client Revenue (Million)', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax4.tick_params(labelrotation=15)
ax4.set_ylabel('Revenue', fontsize=12)
ax4.set_xlabel('Year Onboarded', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

**Toy data**

```
dataset = {'YearOnboarded': [2018,2019,2020,2016,2019,2020,2017,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2016,2016,2016,2017,2016,2018,2016],
           'Revenue2': [100,50,25,30,40,50,60,100,20,40,100,20,5,5,8,4,10,20,8],
           'age_buckets': ['18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59',
                           '18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','18-30','30-39','40-49'],
           'Continents': ['Europe','Asia','Africa','Africa','Other','Asia','Africa','Other','America','America','Europe','Europe',
                      'Other','Europe','Asia','Africa','Asia','Europe','Other']}
df_optimized = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand why this occurs and how to solve the issue.

Thank you!

**Edit:** Found where the problem was coming from and how to solve it. When importing each chunk dataset into the new kernel, one column had mixed data types. Converting the column with mixed data types using `.astype('category')` didn't solve my problem, therefore I had to change the datatype while importing the data with `read_csv` `dtype` and it worked.

Comment: Hi, ```CRev_All_age1```does have a ```Revenue2```column. I updated my question to add a toy dataset, but I can't replicate the Error message with the toy data because my code works.

Comment: Maybe your real data contains a string somewhere instead of a number? Printing out `CRev_All_age1.info()` and similar, could be helpful. Your error message is repeatable if "Revenue2" contains a string somewhere (and integers elsewhere).

Comment: The only data types I have are float64, int64 and object. But before concatenating it used to work well.

Comment: So you mean, after concatenating my chunked dataframes a string could have appeared when all chunked dataframes have the same datatypes?

Comment: Type "object" means string, and is not suitable for the `"Revenue2"` column. Your toy data only has `integer` and `object` columns. Which column is of type `float64`? By the way, are you using the latest seaborn version (0.11)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue likely stems from a character in Revenue2 which pandas does not recognize as an integer when loading the data from whatever filetype you're using to save your data chunks.  pandas reads the entire column as an object even if there's only one element in the column that can't be interpreted as an integer.  In the example, I've used `-` to represent this string character with no integer equivalent.
If you run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'YearOnboarded': [2018,2019,2020,2016,2019,2020,2017,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2016,2016,2016,2017,2016,2018,2016],
           'Revenue2': ["-",50,25,30,40,50,60,100,20,40,100,20,5,5,8,4,10,20,8],
           'age_buckets': ['18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59',
                           '18-30','30-39','40-49','50-59','18-30','30-39','40-49'],
           'Continents': ['Europe','Asia','Africa','Africa','Other','Asia','Africa','Other','America','America','Europe','Europe',
                      'Other','Europe','Asia','Africa','Asia','Europe','Other']})

df['Revenue2'] = df['Revenue2'].astype(int)
```

You'll get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

which is helpful because it indicates the first offending character, then you can replace that character with a filler, and try again:

```
df['Revenue2'] = df.Revenue2.astype(str).str.replace('-','0').astype(int)
df['Revenue2'] = df['Revenue2'].astype(int)
```

eventually, I think you should be able to remove all invalid characters, and have a column that's all integers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer quite useful. I solve the issue differently though, I found that there was mixed datatypes in one column which then lead to the error. So in I specified the ```dtype```while importing my data and it solved the issue.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, and that you found an even better solution.  Maybe you could post your answer?